# Can we lower the two-day minimum wait for placing a bounty to one day for smaller Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, time-limit

After posting a question, can we lower the two-day minimum wait for placing a bounty to, for example, one day, for smaller, more inactive Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: It would be useful to give a few reasons why this might be a good idea

Answer (score 13):

Why? Especially on smaller sites, chances are the question is still on the front page, so it gets enough attention without a bounty. Also, one day may not be enough for the community to determine if the question is a good fit or not (off-topic, too broad, etc.), and a bounty could be misused to protect it from being closed.

If I'd were that desperate, I'd probably mention in a comment that I'm willing to offer a 100-point bounty for a good answer (and delete it after posting the bounty).

Answer (score 10):

If anything, the bounty waiting period should be **longer** on smaller sites. The effect of the bounty is to keep a question visible after it would have otherwise fallen off the front page and incentivize answers for it. On smaller sites, the front page moves much slower which means that a question is still visible on the front page after a couple of days.